# Jquery session time out dialog not working

Tags: jquery

it getting logging me out after 15 minutes even after user is idle  or active  and on the mouse move it show in log as active status ...

```
var timeout = 5000;
$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function () {
    console.log("idle");
    $("#status").html("User is idle :(").css("backgroundColor", "silver");
    var active = $.timeoutDialog({
        timeout: 780,
        countdown: 120,
        logout_redirect_url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + appContext + "/medikmError",
        restart_on_yes: true
    });
});
$(document).bind("active.idleTimer", function () {
    console.log("active");
});
$.idleTimer(timeout);
```

Comment: go with this http://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/  it may help you out..

Comment: another http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u3VKe/1/